# Why am I getting a different result when I use slash at the end of the regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Why when I use slash at the end of the regex I get a different result compared to when I am not using it? Even though it should match it in the same way.

with slash: `re.match('data/(?P<yyyy>[12]\d{3})(?P<mm>0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?P<dd>3[0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|0?[1-9])/', 'data/20221231/file01.csv').groupdict()`

gives me: `{‘dd’: ‘31’, ‘mm’: ‘12’, ‘yyyy’: ‘2022’}`

without slash: `re.match('data/(?P<yyyy>[12]\d{3})(?P<mm>0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?P<dd>3[0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|0?[1-9])', 'data/20221231/file01.csv').groupdict()`

gives me: `{‘dd’: ‘23’, ‘mm’: ‘1’, ‘yyyy’: ‘2022’}`

Comment: Because `0?[1-9]|1[0-2]` uses first branch of alteration and matches only `1` with it. And presence of `/` in the end of pattern makes it match all digits of the date.

Comment: It is strange that you have the `0?` because clearly your data format is fixed-length (4+2+2 digits). Are you really expecting 7 digit dates? Then isn't `2023111` ambiguous? You should just remove those `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `0?[1-9]|1[0-2]` uses first branch of alteration and [matches only `1`](https://regex101.com/r/ASUrIC/1) with it: second branch of alteration will be used only if first branch prevents pattern matching.

Your second pattern matches not all digits of the date. Presence of `/` in the end of pattern makes it match all digits.

If you cannot for some reason use `/` in your pattern, use at least `\b`. It will have similar effect, in sense that all digits of that block will be matched.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/RbGsXh/1).